# AS3 - reset delay on Timer

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, timer

I have a private `Timer` object in an AS3 Class called `_countDownTimer`.
When the class is instantiated, I also initialize the Timer once like so with some arbitrary delay

```
_countDownTimer =new Timer(10000, 1);
_countDownTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onCue,false,0,true);
```

The problem is I need to change the delay time every time the Timer runs. 
So in another method I first redefine a  private var **_newDelayTime** and then call `startMyTimer()` to  redefine the delay and start the `_countDownTimer`.

My question is, should this work properly?

Do I ALSO need to instantiate a NEW _countDownTimer and re-add the listener every time I change the delay?

```
private function startMyTimer():void{
    _countDownTimer.reset();
    _countDownTimer.stop();
    _countDownTimer.delay=_newDelayTime;
    _countDownTimer.start();
}

private function onCue(e:TimerEvent):void{
    trace('do stuff');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need (or want) to create a whole new timer object.

Setting the delay while the timer is running is perfectly acceptable.

Do note though, that setting the delay resets the timer, as per the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html#delay):

> If you set the `delay` interval while the timer is running, the timer will restart at the same `repeatCount` iteration.

So, if the timer doesn't actually need to stop, take off the `1` repeat count when you instantiate (and start it), and then just change the delay whenever you need to.

```
_countDownTimer.delay=_newDelayTime; //no need to reset/stop/restart
```

Answer (score 1):

as I know, as3 Timer class is not precise in counting time... it depends on how fast listener function executes (waits until function finishes its job and continues counting). I prefer using greensock... but if it's not so important for you to have precise time than you can do something like this:

```
private function onCue(e:TimerEvent):void
    {
    trace(e.currentTarget.delay);
    _newDelayTime = Math.round(Math.random() * 999) + 1;
    startMyTimer();
    trace('do stuff');
}
```

you can manipulate with `_newDelayTime` diffenetly... this should work properly and you wont need to re-add listeners

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis ... I faced a similar issue with precision of Timer in an app.
Organis found a way to write a PreciseTimer class that avoid delays in Timer class here if You want to take a look... 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73689625/as3-is-giving-a-delay-timerevent-issue
Have a nice day my friend!