# AS3 Is Giving A Delay / TimerEvent Issue?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, timer, delay

Hello from the past everybody. ;)

OK, Flash is dead, however I wanted to retry an old stuff just today.

My interval delay ticks for each (one) second.

Everything seems to be fine except that I have a delay problem between the time displayed on the debugger and my living room's clock.

Since the Timer call is:

```
new Timer(1000);
```

I don't understand how that some code may not be executed within such a long delay.

Here is some minimum testable code.
You may copy/paste the code provided on **frame 1** to test the issue.
 Stage is `1024 * 400` (works with `550 * 400` too).

The meaning of this is to build a chess clock application for my pleasure only (So why not AS3 for this purpose?).

Any advice please?
Best regards and thank You in advance!!!

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
import flash.text.TextFormatAlign;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.Graphics;

var container1:Sprite = new Sprite();
var container2:Sprite = new Sprite();
var margin1:uint = 20
var display1: TextField = new TextField();
var tFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();

////////////////  2 TEST !!! (970)   ////////
var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000);

var time:uint = 0;
var seconds:String;
var minutes:String;
var hours:String;
var date = new Date();


dateInit();
display1Init();

//timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,changeDate);

timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,changeDate);
timer.start();

function dateInit()
{
    date.hours = date.minutes = date.seconds = date.milliseconds = 0;
    
    trace(date);
    createContainer(container1);
    createContainer(container2)
}

function createContainer(aSprite:Sprite) { addChild(aSprite); }

function display1Init()
{
    container1.addChild(display1);
    drawContainer1();
    drawContainer2();
    display1.width = 140;
    display1.height = 80;
    display1.background = true;
    display1.x = container1.width/2+ margin1/2 - display1.width/2 ;
    display1.y = 100;
    //display1.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
    //tFormat.align = TextFormatAlign.CENTER;
    tFormat.size = 26;
    tFormat.leftMargin = 35;
    tFormat.rightMargin = 35;
    tFormat.bold = true
    display1.border = true;
    display1.text=("\n" + date.hours + "." + "00" + "." + "00" + "\n\n");
    display1.setTextFormat(tFormat);
}

function drawContainer1():void
{
    var g:Graphics = container1.graphics
    g.lineStyle(1,0x000000);
    g.beginFill(0x996666)
    g.drawRoundRect(margin1,margin1,(stage.stageWidth/2)-margin1*2,(stage.stageHeight)-margin1*2,30,30);
    g.endFill();
}

function drawContainer2():void
{
    var g:Graphics = container2.graphics
    g.lineStyle(1,0x000000);
    g.beginFill(0x996666)
    g.drawRoundRect(container1.width+margin1,margin1,container1.width,(stage.stageHeight)-margin1*2,30,30);
    g.endFill();
}

////////////////////// UPDATE ////////////

function formatDate():void
{
    if(date.seconds<10){ seconds = "0"+date.seconds }
    else{ seconds = date.seconds}
    
    if(date.minutes<10){ minutes = "0"+date.minutes }
    else{ minutes = date.minutes }
}

function changeDate(e:TimerEvent):void
{
    date.seconds = timer.currentCount;
    formatDate();
    display1.text=("\n" + date.hours + "." + minutes + "." + seconds + "\n\n");
    display1.setTextFormat(tFormat);
    
    e.updateAfterEvent();
    
    if (timer.currentCount>59)
    {
        date.seconds = 0;
        //timer.stop();
        timer.reset();
        timer.start();
    }
    
    e.updateAfterEvent();
}
```

Comment: Please explain, what is the problem. It is unclear.

Comment: @Organis I think he means that there is a delay/offset between real world's clock saying that 1 second has passed versus the AS3 function (taking longer) to update a textField. It should update every 1 second, but I guess the code takes longer. I cannot test any AS3 (no IDE on this computer).

Comment: @tatactic Welcome back. Nice to see you still use AS3. I will return to it myself when these [multimedia API](https://github.com/airsdk/Adobe-Runtime-Support/discussions/1628)'s happen... Anyways please clarify the problem. Is it a delay in updating the time in a textField (_ie:_ it's taking longer than 1 second of real-world time)?

Comment: @Organis and VC.One : True I've a delay between real time and flash time after +- 3minutes.
The code task is only supposed to display the time, apply my TextFormat each second and that's all. So, I don't understand this issue...
I would like to fix it before to add the second clock.
One clock for the whites / one for the blacks like in a real chess game.

Comment: @Organis thank You... Yeap I'm back to AS3, I miss flash ;)

Comment: @tatactic I'd not measure time with **Timer**s and such. **Flash Player** is not a real-time environment, all the events are handled in the relevant phase which is a part of frame-to-frame loop and can lag in a really ungodly way. It is much better to measure the difference between the two **Date** objects, one that represents the start time, and the other is the current time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that.

```
package
{
    public class PreciseTimer
    {
        private var start:Date;
        
        public function PreciseTimer()
        {
            reset();
        }
        
        // Resets the precise timer.
        public function reset():void
        {
            start = new Date;
        }
        
        // Returns the difference between instantiation/reset
        // and the present moment — in milliseconds.
        public function getTimer():int
        {
            return (new Date).valueOf() - start.valueOf();
        }
    }
}
```

Then, the usage:

```
import PreciseTimer;

var PT = new PreciseTimer;

// ...

// At any given moment:
trace(PT.getTimer(), "milliseconds passed.");
```

Now you are free to convert and display the obtained value in any way you want.

Comment: Thank You a lot, +1 anyway before I try it. Best regards!!! It sounds nice to my brain :)
It sounds better than to put a fps to 60 to get a more acute result to make a "Timer MovieClip".

Comment: Nice done! I have to deal with it now in the app... THX a lot!!!
Have a nice day!!!
Solved at first glance AMO.

Comment: You killed Delay @Organis Aaaaaaargh :)